# MySQL get distinct values and count how many of each,display count highest to lower

Tags: mysql, database

i want to print row fisrt having the highest c value and then lower values in other rows

Comment: It will help if you post a description of your tables, and maybe a sample of whatever query you've tried so far. And also maybe a simple sample of the output your looking for. Also, your title asks about "distinct" but your question does not. What do you want to be DISTINCT?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT item, COUNT(*) as num FROM theTable GROUP BY item ORDER BY num DESC
```

Comment: yes this is the correct solution for which i am looking,thanks for your help

Comment: Please choose an answer as your official answer, use the green check mark below the up/down vote arrows. It helps everyone who searches later for the same kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

```
... ORDER BY c DESC, other_rows
```

Comment: yes this is the correct solution for which i am looking,thanks for your help